# How can I concatenate set of results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, set, concatenation

I would like to join results returned in the set in MySQL with a comma as a separator string.

For example, set returned contains:

```
COLUMN_X
john
jerry
maria
joseph
gugla
```

I would like to receive the result as:

```
COLUMN_X-concat
john,jerry,maria,joseph,gugla
```

is that possible? thanks.

```
SELECT CONCAT(rooms.ID,",") FROM rooms AS rooms LEFT JOIN inter AS i ON rooms.ID=i.value WHERE xxx=999
```

doesn't work as I would like it to as it returns separate results.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_X SEPARATOR ',') FROM <<table>> GROUP BY NULL
```

See [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: When I run this query against a table of my own, I receive the error `Can't group on 'GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')'`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nate: Show your query.

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM products p GROUP BY 1`

Comment: @Nate: Try `... GROUP BY NULL` instead.

Comment: If like me, you got several columns to group, use DISTINCT to get rid of duplicates
( cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561650/mysql-group-concat-duplicates)

Comment: @StefanGehrig it doesn't work in SQuirrel (SQL client version 3.1.2), do you have any solution for it?

Comment: Error: 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not recognized as a function or procedure.

Comment: @AmitaPatil: What MySQL version do you use? And you're sure that you're using MySQL at all?