# mysql GROUP_CONCAT duplicates

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat

I make my join from a farmTOanimal table like this.  There is a similar farmTotool table

```
id | FarmID  | animal
 1 |    1    | cat
 2 |    1    | dog
```

When I join my tables in a view, I get a result that looks like this

```
FarmID | animal | tool
   1   |  cat   | shovel
   1   |  dog   | shovel
   1   |  cat   | bucket
   1   |  dog   | bucket
```

Now, I do GROUP BY FarmID, and GROUP_CONCAT(animal) and GROUP_CONCAT(tool), i get

```
FarmID |     animals     |         tools
  1    | cat,dog,cat,dog | shovel,shovel,bucket,bucket
```

But, what I really want is a result that looks like this.  How can I do it?

```
FarmID | animals |    tools
  1    | cat,dog | shovel,bucket
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(UNIQUE(`animal`))` not working?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You need to use the `DISTINCT` option:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT animal)
```

Comment: DISTINCT displays same rows content as one. For ex. row1='abc', row2='def', row3='abc'. The GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT row) will result abc,def which supposed to be abc,def,abc. What's is the solution other than using DISTINCT?

Comment: Gah, thank you. I tried DISTINCT, but didn't put it inside the GROUP_CONCAT, not sure what I expected that to do. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @JamVille, this solution only works if row column contents are indeed distinct. What if the contents are not distinct, how can we select the values only once?

Comment: @JamVille If you use GROUP_CONCAT() without the DISTINCT keyword that will do what you ask for in your example, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to change the default separator `,` use this syntax :

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT animal || '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT animals)

Comment: Your answer is essentially a duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561650/mysql-group-concat-duplicates/4561977#4561977).