# Transpose column result in resultset to rows

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

i have a resultset like this

```
Continent   Country
------- -------
Asia    Japan
Asia    Russia
Asia    India
Europe  Britain
Europe  France
```

from query

```
select continent,country from tablexxx
```

i want result in the format

```
Continent   Country
------- -------
Asia    Japan,Russia,India
Europe  Britain,France
```

I have heard of pivot tables. but it seems difficult to me...
any help with the query please :)

Here's my final solution in SQL Server , it works...:)

```
SELECT     continents, Countries = replace
                          ((SELECT Countries AS [data()]
                              FROM tblXXX
                              WHERE  continents = a.continents
                              ORDER BY continents FOR xml path('')), ' ',  ',' )
FROM       tblXXXa
WHERE     continents IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY continents
```

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: for mysql see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561650/mysql-group-concat-duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MySQL you need to use GROUP_CONCAT

Example:

```
SELECT continent, GROUP_CONCAT(county ORDER BY country) as Countries 
FROM tablexxx
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY continent
```

**Link**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: thanx a ton...found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COALESCE function to build a comma-delimited list from rows, like in this example:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)

SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))
FROM SalesCallsEmployees
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1

SELECT @EmployeeList
```

Comment: This will not work, except in as a building block in procedural code, is really not SQL however.

Comment: i wanted to write a single query for this, without use of any variables

Comment: You can put the concept into a UDF. That's what I did. If the suggestion from @Johan works though, that might be better.