# SQL Concatenate Joined Results into Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table1:
id (uniqueidentifier, primarykey)
title (varchar(50))

Table2:
id (uniqueidentifier, primarykey)
table1id (uniqueidentifier, foreignkey to table1)
category (varchar(50))
```

I also have the following SQL to return to me all results from Table1 and all their respective categories from Table2.

```
select t1.*, t2.category as cat from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.table1id
```

The problem is, there could be multiple results for category, so how can I concatenate them by comma into the column for `cat`?

For example, Table2 could contain the following data:

```
Table2 row 1:
id = 1
table1id = 1
category = "abc"

Table2 row 2:
id = 2
table1id = 1
category = "def"
```

See how the two records have the same `table1id` but different values for `category`.

How can I concatenate both (or more) potential values by comma and return it as a single string to the resulting column `cat` from the query above?

```
Desired output:
t1.id = 1
t1.title = table1 title
cat = abc, def
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_concat` on `t2.category` and group by the other columns you want to select.

```
select t1.id, t1.title, group_concat(t2.category) as cat from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.table1id
group by t1.id, t1.title
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be grouping (i.e. it's not removing duplicates).  For example, it is showing `IE8122014-PHL6,IE8122014-PHL6,IE8122014-PHL6`.  How can I remove these duplicates and only show the category once per row?

Comment: **Edit:** I tried `group_concat(DISTINCT t2.category)` and it works fine per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561650/mysql-group-concat-duplicates