# Display duplicate results of group concat

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query...

```
SELECT users.*, student_subject.*, GROUP_CONCAT(written.score separator ' - ') as Wscore,SUM(written.score) as total, SUM(written.item) as item 

FROM users 
          JOIN written 
             ON 
                users.idnumber=written.idnumber 
          JOIN student_subject 
            ON 
                written.idnumber=student_subject.idnumber 

WHERE student_subject.teacher='$login_session' 
      AND written.section='$section' 
      AND written.level='$level' 
      AND written.year='$year' 
      AND written.subject='$subject' 
      AND users.gender='male' 
      AND written.period='first' 

GROUP BY written.idnumber order by users.lname
```

The problem is the result of group concat display a duplicate results

ex. 4-4-5-7-4-5

to

4-4-5-7-4-5-4-4-5-7-4-5-4-4-5-7-4-5-4-4-5-7-4-5...

How can I remove those duplicates?

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4561977) s.o. article

Comment: I tried to use distinct before but the result is  4-5-7... it should be  4-4-5-7-4-5

Comment: can you create a [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)