# How can i do this multiple JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I need to build a query with multiple JOIN, to be more especific, 2 JOINS, but it gets duplicated results, check this:

My current tables:

food_shops

```
id, slug, name
```

categories_food_shops

```
id, id_cat, id_food_shop
```

pictures_food_shops

```
id, pic_slug, id_food_shop
```

And I need to get * from food_shops, the id_cat from categories_food_shops and pic_slug from pictures_food_shops...

My current query is like this:

```
SELECT food_shops.id, food_shops.slug, food_shops.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(categories_food_shops.id_category) as categories, 
GROUP_CONCAT(pictures_food_shops.slug) as pictures 
FROM
food_shops 
JOIN categories_food_shops 
    ON food_shops.id = categories_food_shops.id_food_shop 
JOIN pictures_food_shops 
    ON food_shops.id = pictures_food_shops.id_food_shop 
GROUP BY food_shops.slug, pictures_food_shops.id_food_shop
```

But since my pictures_food_shops have more results as the categories_food_shops, my result is gettin "quadruplicated":

[image]

What can I do to prevent this and get only the correct amount of categories?
Only 1 at the first row, 3 and 5 in the second one and 7,1,6 at the last one?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql GROUP\_CONCAT duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561650/mysql-group-concat-duplicates)

Comment: Just to clarify where is id_category coming from?  I dont see it in your schema above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
...
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories_food_shops.id_category) as categories, 
....
```

This should work for pictures also.

[Here is the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)  with `DISTINCT` usage example.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need, so simple :P kkkkkkkkk, Thank you very much

Comment: @user3159043 Glad to help, please upvote and select answer if it worked for you, thanks!